# Alphabet pattern including astericks -Java

Tags: java

I'm new to Java and stuck with this assignment, Although I have completed it somehow but I want to do it without the `if-else` statement.

```
  for(int i=0; i<numRows; i++) 
  {
     for(int j=0; j<numRows-i; j++) 
     {
         System.out.print(" ");
     }
    for(int k = 0; k <= i*2; k++) 
    {
    if(k%2 == 1)
        System.out.print("A");
    else
        System.out.print("*");
    }
        System.out.println();  
}
```

Output:

```
    *
   *A*
  *A*A*
 *A*A*A*
*A*A*A*A*
```

Comment: I think this question needs to be asked on another community on stack exchange. [http://codereview.stackexchange.com/](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: "I want to do it without the if-else statement." - why? You could use a map but that wouldn't make it easier to read or faster to execute.

Comment: @Thomas because that's what my teacher wants -.- I just can't seem to find a way out!

Comment: Is your teacher okay with a ternary?

Comment: @DylanMeeus He asked to use `for-loops` ONLY. Is it possible that way?

Comment: Alternatively you could print an asterisk and then print `A*` as many times as needed (i.e. 0 - 4 times).

Comment: @Mogambo it's possible, the way Thomas mentioned for example. Academic exercises don't always tend to make sense for actual programming :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since each row starts with an asterisk and then repeats `A*` n times (where n is row number - 1, i.e. 0 for the first row, 1 for the second etc.) you can do that in your loop, i.e. print the first asterisk and then repeat `A*` as often as needed.

Example:

```
for( int i = 0; i < numRows; i++ )
{
  //print whitespace for correct indentation
  for( int j = 0; j < numRows - i; j++ )
  {
    System.out.print( " " );
  }

  //print the first asterisk
  System.out.print( "*" );

  //print as many A* as needed, i.e. row-1 times 
  for( int k = 0; k < i; k++ )
  {
    System.out.print( "A*" );        
  }
  System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I just did! Cheers bro!

Answer (score 2):

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int numRows = 5;
        String s = "*A*";
        String space = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < numRows - 1; i++) {
            space += " ";
        }

        System.out.println(space + "*" + space);
        for (int i = 0; i < numRows - 1; i++) {
            String str = space.substring(0, space.length() - i - 1);
            System.out.println(str + s + str);
            s += "A*";
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You change your if-else to the line mentioned in the following code

```
int numRows=5;
    for(int i=0; i<numRows; i++) 
      {
         for(int j=0; j<numRows-i; j++) 
         {
             System.out.print(" ");
         }
        for(int k = 0; k <= i*2; k++) 
        {
            //calculates according to mod value of k
            char ch=(char) (((k%2)*'A')+((1-k%2)*'*'));
            System.out.print(ch);
        }
            System.out.println();  
    }
```

Comment: That seems to be way too complicated and thus error prone.

Comment: What exactly is happening here `char ch=(char) (((k%2)*'A')+((1-k%2)*'*'));`?

Comment: if k is even then "(k%2)*'A'" will produce 0 else "((1-k%2)*'*')" will produce 0, hence remaining part will be casted to a char hence ch will be "A" or "*"

Answer (score -1):

CODE PART 1

```
    String nom,silaba;
    int nomlong,longi,z=0;
    char ass;
    nom=txt1.getText();
    nomlong=nom.length();
    txtapex.setText("");
    do{    
    silaba=nom.substring(0+z, 1+z);
    char c=silaba.charAt(0);
    int ascii = (int) c;
    switch(ascii){
        case 65:
                for(int j=0;j<5;j++){
                    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {                            
                        if(i+j==0){
                        txtapex.append("     ");
                        }else if(j-i==-3){
                        txtapex.append("     ");
                        }else if(i==0){
                        txtapex.append("8   ");
                        }else if(i==3){
                        txtapex.append("8   ");
                        }else if(j==0){
                        txtapex.append("8   ");
                        }else if(j==2){
                        txtapex.append("8   ");
                        }else{
                        txtapex.append("     ");
                        }                          
                    }
                        txtapex.append("\n");
                }
                               txtapex.append("\n");                    
            break;
        case 97:
                 for(int j=0;j<5;j++){
                    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {                            
                        if(i+j==0){
                        txtapex.append("     ");
                        }else if(j-i==-3){
                        txtapex.append("     ");
                        }else if(i==0){
                        txtapex.append("8   ");
                        }else if(i==3){
                        txtapex.append("8   ");
                        }else if(j==0){
                        txtapex.append("8   ");
                        }else if(j==2){
                        txtapex.append("8   ");
                        }else{
                        txtapex.append("     ");
                        }                          
                    }
                        txtapex.append("\n");
                }
                               txtapex.append("\n");               
            break;
            case 66:
                for(int j=0;j<5;j++){
                    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {                            
                        if(i==0){
                        txtapex.append("8   ");
                        }else if(j-i==-3){
                        txtapex.append("     ");
                        }else if(j==0){
                        txtapex.append("8   ");
                        }else if(j-i==-2){
                        txtapex.append("8   ");
                        }else if(j==1){
                        txtapex.append("     ");
                        }else if(j-i==-1){
                        txtapex.append("     ");
                        }else if(j==2){
                        txtapex.append("8   ");
                        }else if(j+i==6){
                        txtapex.append("8   ");
                        }else if(j+i==7){
                        txtapex.append("     ");
                        }else if(j==4){
                        txtapex.append("8   ");
                        }else{
                        txtapex.append("     ");
                        }                          
                    }
                        txtapex.append("\n");
                }
                               txtapex.append("\n");                    
            break;
        case 98:
                 for(int j=0;j<5;j++){
                    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {                            
                        if(i==0){
                        txtapex.append("8   ");
                        }else if(j-i==-3){
                        txtapex.append("     ");
                        }else if(j==0){
                        txtapex.append("8   ");
                        }else if(j-i==-2){
                        txtapex.append("8   ");
                        }else if(j==1){
                        txtapex.append("     ");
                        }else if(j-i==-1){
                        txtapex.append("     ");
                        }else if(j==2){
                        txtapex.append("8   ");
                        }else if(j+i==6){
                        txtapex.append("8   ");
                        }else if(j+i==7){
                        txtapex.append("     ");
                        }else if(j==4){
                        txtapex.append("8   ");
                        }else{
                        txtapex.append("     ");
                        }                          
                    }
                        txtapex.append("\n");
                }
                               txtapex.append("\n");           
            break;
        case 67:
                for(int j=0;j<5;j++){
                    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

                        if(i+j==0){
                        txtapex.append("     ");
                        }else if(j-i==4){
                        txtapex.append("     ");
                        }else if(i==0){
                        txtapex.append("8   ");
                        }else if(j-i==3){
                        txtapex.append("8   ");
                        }else if(j==0){
                        txtapex.append("8   ");
                        }else if(j==4){
                        txtapex.append("8   ");
                        }else{
                        txtapex.append("     ");
                        }                         
                    }
                        txtapex.append("\n");
                }
                               txtapex.append("\n");
            break;
        case 99:
                for(int j=0;j<5;j++){
                    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

                        if(i+j==0){
                        txtapex.append("     ");
                        }else if(j-i==4){
                        txtapex.append("     ");
                        }else if(i==0){
                        txtapex.append("8   ");
                        }else if(j-i==3){
                        txtapex.append("8   ");
                        }else if(j==0){
                        txtapex.append("8   ");
                        }else if(j==4){
                        txtapex.append("8   ");
                        }else{
                        txtapex.append("     ");
                        }                         
                    }
                        txtapex.append("\n");
                }
                               txtapex.append("\n");
            break;
        case 68:
                for(int j=0;j<5;j++){
                    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

                        if(j-i==-3){
                        txtapex.append("     ");
                        }else if(i+j==7){
                        txtapex.append("     ");
                        }else if(i==0){
                        txtapex.append("8   ");
                        }else if(i==3){
                        txtapex.append("8   ");
                        }else if(j==0){
                        txtapex.append("8   ");
                        }else if(j==4){
                        txtapex.append("8   ");
                        }else{
                        txtapex.append("     ");
                        }                         
                    }
                        txtapex.append("\n");
                }
                               txtapex.append("\n");
            break;
        case 100:
               for(int j=0;j<5;j++){
                    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

                        if(j-i==-3){
                        txtapex.append("     ");
                        }else if(i+j==7){
                        txtapex.append("     ");
                        }else if(i==0){
                        txtapex.append("8   ");
                        }else if(i==3){
                        txtapex.append("8   ");
                        }else if(j==0){
                        txtapex.append("8   ");
                        }else if(j==4){
                        txtapex.append("8   ");
                        }else{
                        txtapex.append("     ");
                        }                         
                    }
                        txtapex.append("\n");
                }
                               txtapex.append("\n");
            break;
        case 69:
                for(int j=0;j<5;j++){
                    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

                        if(j*i==0){
                        txtapex.append("8   ");
                        }else if(j==2){
                        txtapex.append("8   ");
                        }else if(j==4){
                        txtapex.append("8   ");
                        }else{
                        txtapex.append("     ");
                        }                         
                    }
                        txtapex.append("\n");
                }
                               txtapex.append("\n");
            break;
        case 101:
               for(int j=0;j<5;j++){
                    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

                        if(j*i==0){
                        txtapex.append("8   ");
                        }else if(j==2){
                        txtapex.append("8   ");
                        }else if(j==4){
                        txtapex.append("8   ");
                        }else{
                        txtapex.append("     ");
                        }                         
                    }
                        txtapex.append("\n");
                }
                               txtapex.append("\n");
            break;
        case 70:
                for(int j=0;j<5;j++){
                    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

                        if(j*i==0){
                        txtapex.append("8   ");
                        }else if(j==2){
                        txtapex.append("8   ");
                        }else{
                        txtapex.append("     ");
                        }                         
                    }
                        txtapex.append("\n");
                }
                               txtapex.append("\n");
            break;
        case 102:
               for(int j=0;j<5;j++){
                    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

                        if(j*i==0){
                        txtapex.append("8   ");
                        }else if(j==2){
                        txtapex.append("8   ");
                        }else{
                        txtapex.append("     ");
                        }                         
                    }
                        txtapex.append("\n");
                }
                               txtapex.append("\n");
            break;
        case 71:
                for(int j=0;j<5;j++){
                    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

                        if(j+i==0){
                        txtapex.append("     ");
                        }else if(j-i==4){
                        txtapex.append("     ");
                        }else if(j==0){
                        txtapex.append("8   ");
                        }else if(i==0){
                        txtapex.append("8   ");
                        }else if(j==4){
                        txtapex.append("8   ");
                        }else if(j+i==3){
                        txtapex.append("     ");
                        }else if(j==2){
                        txtapex.append("8   ");
                        }else if(j==4){
                        txtapex.append("8   ");
                        }else if(j*i==3){
                        txtapex.append("     ");
                        }else if(i==3){
                        txtapex.append("8   ");
                        }else if(j*i==3){
                        txtapex.append("     ");
                        }else{
                        txtapex.append("     ");
                        }                         
                    }
                        txtapex.append("\n");
                }
                               txtapex.append("\n");
            break;
        case 103:
               for(int j=0;j<5;j++){
                    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

                        if(j+i==0){
                        txtapex.append("     ");
                        }else if(j-i==4){
                        txtapex.append("     ");
                        }else if(j==0){
                        txtapex.append("8   ");
                        }else if(i==0){
                        txtapex.append("8   ");
                        }else if(j==4){
                        txtapex.append("8   ");
                        }else if(j+i==3){
                        txtapex.append("     ");
                        }else if(j==2){
                        txtapex.append("8   ");
                        }else if(j==4){
                        txtapex.append("8   ");
                        }else if(j*i==3){
                        txtapex.append("     ");
                        }else if(i==3){
                        txtapex.append("8   ");
                        }else if(j*i==3){
                        txtapex.append("     ");
                        }else{
                        txtapex.append("     ");
                        }                         
                    }
                        txtapex.append("\n");
                }
                               txtapex.append("\n");
            break;
        case 72:
                for(int j=0;j<5;j++){
                    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

                        if(i==0){
                        txtapex.append("8   ");
                        }else if(i==3){
                        txtapex.append("8   ");
                        }else if(j==2){
                        txtapex.append("8   ");
                        }else{
                        txtapex.append("     ");
                        }                         
                    }
                        txtapex.append("\n");
                }
                               txtapex.append("\n");
            break;
        case 104:
               for(int j=0;j<5;j++){
                    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

                        if(i==0){
                        txtapex.append("8   ");
                        }else if(i==3){
                        txtapex.append("8   ");
                        }else if(j==2){
                        txtapex.append("8   ");
                        }else{
                        txtapex.append("     ");
                        }                         
                    }
                        txtapex.append("\n");
                }
                               txtapex.append("\n");
            break;
        case 73:
                for(int j=0;j<5;j++){
                    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

                        if(j-i==4){
                        txtapex.append("     ");
                        }else if(j+i==0){
                        txtapex.append("     ");
                        }else if(j==0){
                        txtapex.append("8   ");
                        }else if(j==4){
                        txtapex.append("8   ");
                        }else if(i==2){
                        txtapex.append("8   ");
                        }else{
                        txtapex.append("     ");
                        }                         
                    }
                        txtapex.append("\n");
                }
                               txtapex.append("\n");
            break;
        case 105:
               for(int j=0;j<5;j++){
                    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

                        if(j-i==4){
                        txtapex.append("     ");
                        }else if(j+i==0){
                        txtapex.append("     ");
                        }else if(j==0){
                        txtapex.append("8   ");
                        }else if(j==4){
                        txtapex.append("8   ");
                        }else if(i==2){
                        txtapex.append("8   ");
                        }else{
                        txtapex.append("     ");
                        }                         
                    }
                        txtapex.append("\n");
                }
                               txtapex.append("\n");
            break;
        case 74:
                for(int j=0;j<5;j++){
                    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

                        if(j==0){
                        txtapex.append("8   ");
                        }else if(j-i==2){
                        txtapex.append("     ");
                        }else if(j-i==3){
                        txtapex.append("8   ");
                        }else if(i==2){
                        txtapex.append("8   ");
                        }else{
                        txtapex.append("     ");
                        }                         
                    }
                        txtapex.append("\n");
                }
                               txtapex.append("\n");
            break;
        case 106:
               for(int j=0;j<5;j++){
                    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

                        if(j==0){
                        txtapex.append("8   ");
                        }else if(j-i==2){
                        txtapex.append("     ");
                        }else if(j-i==3){
                        txtapex.append("8   ");
                        }else if(i==2){
                        txtapex.append("8   ");
                        }else{
                        txtapex.append("     ");
                        }                         
                    }
                        txtapex.append("\n");
                }
                               txtapex.append("\n");
            break;
            case 75:
                for(int j=0;j<5;j++){
                    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

                        if(i==0){
                        txtapex.append("8   ");
                        }else if(j-i==1){
                        txtapex.append("8   ");
                        }else if(j+i==3){
                        txtapex.append("8   ");
                        }else{
                        txtapex.append("     ");
                        }                         
                    }
                        txtapex.append("\n");
                }
                               txtapex.append("\n");
            break;
        case 107:
               for(int j=0;j<5;j++){
                    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

                        if(i==0){
                        txtapex.append("8   ");
                        }else if(j-i==1){
                        txtapex.append("8   ");
                        }else if(j+i==3){
                        txtapex.append("8   ");
                        }else{
                        txtapex.append("     ");
                        }                         
                    }
                        txtapex.append("\n");
                }
                               txtapex.append("\n");
            break;
        case 76:
                for(int j=0;j<5;j++){
                    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

                        if(i==0){
                        txtapex.append("     ");
                        }else if(i==1){
                        txtapex.append("8   ");
                        }else if(j==4){
                        txtapex.append("8   ");
                        }else{
                        txtapex.append("     ");
                        }                         
                    }
                        txtapex.append("\n");
                }
                               txtapex.append("\n");
            break;
        case 108:
               for(int j=0;j<5;j++){
                    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

                        if(i==0){
                        txtapex.append("     ");
                        }else if(i==1){
                        txtapex.append("8   ");
                        }else if(j==4){
                        txtapex.append("8   ");
                        }else{
                        txtapex.append("     ");
                        }                         
                    }
                        txtapex.append("\n");
                }
                               txtapex.append("\n");
            break;
```

Comment: your code is not readable  user want more simplified and readable